# Salesforce sites license and oauth

Tags: force.com-sites, oauth

I could answer this question by spending a day doing it, but has anyone tried using oAuth to log in a sites user?

My concern is that since usernames are not globally unique, but only unique to that org, that salesforce wouldn't have a way to know which portal to log them in on.  I didn't see any parameters to scope the org/portal.

Most of the time, with sites, the answer ends up being, "it doesn't support that"

Comment: Similar idea on the idea exchange http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h0I5AAI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, OAuth is supported only for full licenses - not authenticated sites or portal.  In part, I think, because of the org dependency you mention.